Why does my supabase realtime listener sporadically miss an event?
I have multiple realtime listeners in my iOS project that should be listening for events from supabase realtime. I'm using the current realtimeV2, however it appears that sometimes, without reasoning, it is not fired. Other times it's fired just fine. This is also true of broadcasts.
I have this DataManager class that I'm injecting into the @Environment so I setup a ton of tasks whenever the app is launched, then that object is constantly listening for changes from the DB to keep the user-device up-to-date with current data.
The functionality I'm working with here, is a "QRScanner" that does the following.

DeviceA shows a QR
DeviceB scans QR and modifies data that is present on DeviceA
Data is then changed on DB from DeviceB
DeviceA should update based on that update/delete action.
Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't it's not from missing data as I've confirmed a message is never received.

Here is the init for my DataManager. To re-iterate. This initializer is called at app-launch, and then schedules all of the listeners. This object always exists in the @Environment from the root view
public init(_ client: SupabaseClient) {
    self.client = client
    supabaseUser = nil
    loadingRewards = true
    rewards = []
    rewardWeeklySchedules = []
    customerProfiles = []
    rewardTransactions = []
    
    Task.detached(priority: .high) { @MainActor in
        self.supabaseUser = try? await self.client.auth.user()
        try? await self.refreshProfile()
        try? await self.loadWeeklySchedules()
        try? await self.loadRewards()
    }
    
    Task.detached(priority: .background) { @MainActor in
        let channel = await self.client.realtimeV2.channel("public:messages")
        self.singleProfileRealtimeUpdates(channel)
        self.rewardsUpdatedRealtimeUpdate(channel)
        self.rewardScheduleRealtimeUpdate(channel)
        await channel.subscribe()
    }
}


Here is one of the realtime-listeners that I see the problem most frequently with. What I'm expecting to happen, is that whenever a DeviceB scans DeviceA's qr code, it will present that DeviceA's profile. They make a change to it, and it's pushed to the DB. At that time it should trigger an update on DeviceA so that it's in-sync with the real-data.
func singleProfileRealtimeUpdates(_ channel: RealtimeChannelV2) {
    guard let profile else {
        return
    }
    
    Task.detached(priority: .background) {
        for await update in await channel.postgresChange(UpdateAction.self, table: "reward_profiles", filter: "user_id=eq.\(profile.id)") {
            withAnimation {
                self.profile = try? update.decodeRecord(as: Profile.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            }
        }
    }
}

If you have some other solution, other than Realtime I'm 100% willing to change the way this works. The only thing I can consider is perhaps I need to setup custom channels for each listener, and have them responding uniquely to a particular channel only. Right now I'm just using public:messages for all of them.
I have a limitation I'm concerned about however; This is a white-label app, meaning we're going to rebranding it for a bunch of different clients. I can choose to create custom channels for each branding, or just overall for a particular listener, it makes no difference, but I don't know supabases' limitations on that.

What does Task.detached(priority: .background) { @MainActor actually do? I would've assumed that detached/background and MainActor are incongruous

I think, this specifies that it runs on a background thread, but if an update does happen its triggered on the main thread. Take that with a grain of salt however. What I do know, if I don't have MainActor there, I get a crash periodically.

I just ran a test and it looks like @MainActor overrides the Task.detached(priority: .background). Nothing in those closures is running on a background thread.

Good to know! Thanks for sharing that. I'll update that shortly. Any clue on the darned realtime listener however?

No -- sorry, no insight on that

I'm Guilherme from the Supabase Mobile SDK team.
What may be happening is that your tasks may be starting after the await channel.subscribe() call, which will not include the postgresChange in the subscription, but this case would trigger a precondition failure in your code, do you see any precondition being triggered sometimes?
To fix the above you need to call the postgresChange method out of the Task.detached, example:
func singleProfileRealtimeUpdates(_ channel: RealtimeChannelV2) async {
    guard let profile else {
        return
    }

    let updates = await channel.postgresChange(UpdateAction.self, table: "reward_profiles", filter: "user_id=eq.\(profile.id)")

    Task.detached(priority: .background) {
        for await update in updates  {
            withAnimation {
                self.profile = try? update.decodeRecord(as: Profile.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            }
        }
    }
}

